# Why vector's insert() creates a copy of inserted element and assigns to the copy, not the inserted element?

Tags: c++, vector, insert

Consider an `insert(iterator position, const value_type &x)` call: if no reallocation is happening (capacity != size), then in many implementations of the vector I saw this behavior:

```cpp
     ...
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
     void
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     _M_insert_aux(iterator __position, const _Tp& __x)
 #endif
{
    ...
    if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
    {
       this->_M_impl.construct(this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                   _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(this->_M_impl._M_finish
                           - 1)));
       ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
     #ifndef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
       _Tp __x_copy = __x;
     #endif
       _GLIBCXX_MOVE_BACKWARD3(__position.base(),
                   this->_M_impl._M_finish - 2,
                   this->_M_impl._M_finish - 1);
     #ifndef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
       *__position = __x_copy;
     ...
```

Why not assign `*__position` to `__x`? Doesn't creating a copy result in additional waste of space? Couldn't one get away with avoiding creating the copy?

Comment: Just FYI this is an implementation that your particular version of the compiler is using, it is not tied to `std::vector` API or C++ standard.  Is `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` even set? `c++0x` should not be used, unless you have a really old compiler.

Comment: The fact that the `CXX0X` has `EXPERIMENTAL` in it's name suggests that this is a very old compiler you're using.

Comment: you say "in many implementations of the vector I saw this" but what you posted is one particular version of one particular implementation. It would be better to say where you took it from

Comment: `Doesn't creating a copy result in additional waste of space?` A marginal extra use of automatic storage is usually irrelevant. The storage is released as soon as the function returns. If that were "extra" rather than necessary use of memory that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `__x_copy` is only used if the `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` macro isn't set. This means it is only used in C++98 and C++03 mode.

Nowadays you probably shouldn't be using these old modes without a reason.

The macro name also indicates that you have an old copy of libstc++. It was replaced in 2012: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=734f50238f863ae90d2e8caa2323aaa02380ff48

---

Before moving elements of the container to free up the location at which the new element is supposed to be inserted, a copy of `__x` is made because it is possible that `__x` refers to an element of the container which may be relocated in this operation, invalidating the reference. At least that is what it looks like to me.

If I remember correctly, it was, and still is, allowed to pass references to elements of the same container to its member functions if there are no specific preconditions stating otherwise, as long as these are lvalue references, not rvalue references.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I get it now. this implies that the range insert, given a pair of iterators to the same vector, will cause undefined (or at least not desired) behavior, right?

Comment: @Mampac The range insert has a precondition that none of the iterators point into the container itself, see the table on sequence container requirements in the standard: https://eel.is/c++draft/containers#tab:container.seq.req. Violating the precondition means that the program has undefined behavior.